# Can a 4-dimensional object be visualized using time?

Tags: geometry

Is for example a tesseract the same thing as cube over time? If not, is there a 3-d object that in some sense is a tesseract over time?

EDIT: What I mean is, are 3 dimensional objects in time "real-life" 4-d objects? If so, is it a cube that is a tesseract or some object that is not a cube that nonetheless viewed over time is a tesseract? Or is time not useful since in 4-d geometry they really mean 4 spatial dimensions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but yes, you can visualize a 4-dimensional shape by seeing slices of it as it passes through a three-dimensional hyperplane over time.  See [here](http://imgur.com/gallery/Frqrj)

Answer (score 0):

As often, we can answer a question like this by reducing the dimension by $1$.  We could define $\Bbb R^3$ with one axis time.  In that case we would see a sphere as a circle that started from a point, expanded to maximum radius, then shrank to a point.  If that is useful to you, go for it.  In special relativity and a particular reference frame, we can find a three space perpendicular to the local time axis and look at shapes as they transit that subspace.  In general relativity it is messier.